# Issue related to double precision floating point division in C++

Tags: c++, c++14, double, rounding, floor-division

In C++, we know that we can find the minimum representable double precision value using `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`. The value turns out to be `2.22507e-308` when printed.

Now if a given double value (say `val`) is subtracted from this minimum value and then a division is undertaken with the same previous double value `(val - minval) / val`, I was expecting the answer to be rounded to `0` if the operation `floor((val - minval ) / val)` was performed on the resulting divided value.

To my surprise, the answer is delivered as `1`. Can someone please explain this anomalous behavior?

Consider the following code:

```
int main()
{
  double minval = std::numeric_limits<double>::min(), wg = 8038,    
         ans = floor((wg - minval) / wg); // expecting the answer to round to 0   
  cout << ans; // but the answer actually resulted as 1!
}
```

Comment: Most likely `minval` is so small its subtraction is discarded as `double` doesn't have enough bits to store the needed precision.

Comment: Your reasoning is unclear.

Comment: `min()` is just a smallest not 0 number that can be stored in `double`. It is not about a precision, it does not mean `double` can fit 4.5e+307 numbers between 8037 and 8038.

Comment: So basically what should be the smallest representable double precision value used to get the value rounded to 0 which works for arbitrary double precision values (stated as wg in code above)?

Comment: Based on how you asked that, you're not going to like what the actual value is, which is something like `wg * 0x1P-53`. BTW what are you actually computing for real? Computing zero isn't useful. There is `std::nextafter` which you can use to guarantee that a value becomes slightly lower (but using `nextafter` to nudge `wg / wg` down so that it floors to zero would be silly at best)

Comment: Thanks very much for it. Basically, the application will have to be another question but I am trying to map floating point values to integer intervals. This has current application in sending these intervals to distinct processors. Say there is float range [0, 8038.52] which is sent over 16 processors. I want 0 to map to 0, (0, 8038.52/16] to map to 1, (8038.52/16, 2*8038.52/16] to map to 2, and so on until (15*8038.52/16, 8038.52] to map to 16. There is a client requirement to map these numbers this way for which I was trying the p_n = floor( (w*np +.wg - mindouble)/wg ). wg = 8038.52.

Comment: Rather than working out the math to turn a value into the index (which is probably possible) it seems safer to me to make an array of `{ 0, 8038.52/16, 2*8038.52/16 ... ` (with two successive numbers representing a half-open interval) and then for each value you can search in the array for which interval it is in.

Comment: Yes, I think a search should be an efficient solution especially for double values.. I was only trying to reduce memory footprint since number of processors might be around 10k by doing interval assignments on the fly which works for integers but causes issues with doubles. I think storing an array for this case to maintain correctness should not be an issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

A double typically has around 16 digits of precision.

You're starting with 8038. For simplicity, I'm going to call that `8.038e3`. Since we have around 16 digits of precision, the smallest number we can subtract from that and still get a result different from 8038 is 8038e(3-16) = 8038e-13.

8038 - 2.2e-308 is like reducing the mass of the universe by one electron, and expecting that to affect the mass of the universe by a significant amount.

Actually, relatively speaking, 8038-2.2e-308 is a much *smaller* change than removing a whole electron from the universe--more like removing a minuscule fraction of a single electron from the universe, if that were possible. Even if we were to assume that string theory were correct, even removing one string from the universe would still be a *huge* change compared to subtracting 2.2e-308 from 8038.

Answer (score 0):

The comments and the previous answer correctly attribute the cause to floating point precision issues but there are additional details needed to explain the correct behavior. In fact, even in cases where subtraction cannot be carried out such that the results of the subtraction cannot be represented with the finite precision of floating point numbers, inexact rounding is still performed by the compiler and subtraction is not completely discarded.

As an example, consider the code below.

```
int main()
{
    double b, c, d;
    
    vector<double> a{0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7};
    
    cout << "Subtraction Possible?" << "\t" << "Floor Result" << "\n";
    
    for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {
        
        b = std::nextafter( a[i], 0 );
    
        c = a[i] - b;
    
        d = 1e-17;
        
        if( (bool)(d > c) )
            cout << "True" << "\t";
        else
            cout << "False" << "\t";
        
        cout << setprecision(52) << floor((a[i] - d)/a[i]) << "\n";
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code takes in different double precision values in the form of vector **a** and performs subtraction from **1e-17**. It must be noted that the smallest value that can be subtracted from **0.07** is shown to be **1.387778780781445675529539585113525390625e-17** using std::nextafter for the value **0.07**. This means that 1e-17 is smaller than the smallest value which can be subtracted from any of these numbers. Hence, theoretically, subtraction should not be possible for any of the numbers listed in vector a. If we assume that the subtraction results are discarded, then the answer must always stay **1** but it turns out that sometimes the answer is **0** and other times **1**.

This can be observed from the output of the C++ program as shown below:

```
Subtraction Possible?   Floor Result
False                       0
False                       0
False                       0
False                       0
False                       1
False                       1
False                       1
False                       1
False                       1
```

The reasons lay buried within the Floating Point specification prescribed in the IEEE 754 document. In general the standard specifically states that even in cases where the results of an operation cannot be represented, rounding must be carried out. I quote Page 27, Section 4.3 of the IEEE 754, 2019 document:

> Except where stated otherwise, every operation shall be performed as if it first produced an
> intermediate result correct to infinite precision and with unbounded range, and then rounded that result
> according to one of the attributes in this clause

The statement in further repeated in Section 5.1 of Page 29 as shown below:

> Unless otherwise specified, each of the computational
> operations specified by this standard that returns a numeric result shall be performed as if it first produced
> an intermediate result correct to infinite precision and with unbounded range, and then rounded that
> intermediate result, if necessary, to fit in the destination’s format (see Clause 4 and Clause 7).

C++'s g++ compiler (which I have been testing) correctly and very precisely interprets the standard by implementing nearest rounding stated in Section 4.3.1 of the IEEE 754 document. This has the implication that even when `a[i] - b` is not representable, a numeric result is delivered as if the subtraction first produced an intermediate result correct to infinite precision and with unbounded range, and then rounded that
intermediate result. Hence, it may or may not be the case that `a[i] - b == a[i]` which means that the answer may or may not be `1` depending on whether `a[i] - b` is closer to `a[i]` or it is closer to the next representable value after `a[i]`.

It turns out that `8038 - 2.22507e-308` is closer to `8038` due to which the answer is rounded (using nearest rounding) to `8038` and the final answer is `1` but this is to only state that this behavior does result from the compiler's interpretation of the standard and is not something arbitrary.

I found below references on Floating Point numbers to be very useful. I would recommend reading Cleve Moler's (founder of MATLAB) reference on floating point numbers before going through the IEEE specification for a quick and easy understanding of their behavior.

1. "IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic," in IEEE Std 754-2019 (Revision of IEEE 754-2008) , vol., no., pp.1-84, 22 July 2019, doi: 10.1109/IEEESTD.2019.8766229.
2. Moler, Cleve. “Floating Points.” MATLAB News and Notes. Fall, 1996.